# How to organize data in Java

Tags: java, organization

I was wondering what the easiest and smartest way to organize data for easy retrieval and manipulation. I am creating a program in Java that will keep track of employee information, such as names, number, address, phone numbers, etc. The obvious solution would be to save the information in a text file, but that doesn't seem very smart or elegant. I was looking at databases, but they seem like overkill, since this information will only be accessed by one person at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Databases are not overkill. They're great for organizing data even for embedded systems. (Take a look at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), for example.) Other possibilities, depending on how much data you're talking about, are XML files (for which there are several APIs you could use) and [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) persisted to files.

Comment: +1 There are a number of good, easy-to-use embedded databases, especially since his data appears relational.

Comment: SQLite is basically a textfile anyhow - just with the advantage of not having to worry about all the nitty gritty details. Great for lots of small applications where you don't need the normal server-client dbs.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this kind of question is always like trying to answer, "what kind of car should I buy?" without more information on your needs.

Are you building a desktop application?  Web application?  Terminal app?  What kind of information will you be storing?  How much?  Etc.

Databases arent anything to fear, to be sure, they can offer structured data storage in an easily retrievable and reliable format.  You can also look into embedded databases like HSQL or SQLite or non-relational models like MongoDB (best if you use highly unstructured data).

But I would suggest you share a bit more information on your needs first, then we might be able to tell you if you need the SUV or the sedan.

Comment: i think he's shared the kind of car he wants :-)

Comment: It will be a desktop application and the information is what I said in the op. Basically all it will do is let the user add customers information, be able to edit it and add things, sort through customers and be able to print the information for the customer. Not sure if that helped lol. The printing part of this program may be a little tricky since I will need to figure out how to format it so it looks good.

Comment: @user1104154 - For reporting, just search "java reporting tool". There are lots of good packages around, including open-source ones like [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) and [DynamicReports](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/), as well as several very good proprietary ones.

Comment: Then an SQLite implementation would be a good place to start looking.  It would free you from any need to set up a database system upon installation (i.e. the app would be portable with little setup required).